# Inserted new document in collection does not appear in the DOM

Tags: mongodb, collections, insert, meteor, document

I'm using meteor to insert tasks (divs) in the DOM. There is a collection called 'tasks_lists' stored in local var ocTasksLists so calling

```
var oTaskList = new TaskList();
ocTasksLists.insert(oTaskList);
```

in the client, should include the new task_list in both the DOM and the server mongo database.

First, it is included in the DOM, and few milliseconds after, it disappears from the DOM. I'm cannot find the reason of the problem. The document is inserted in the server mognodb and if I refresh the page (F5) then it does appear in DOM. The insert allow rule in the server returns always true.

There is not any problem while changing or removing tasks_lists.

Thank you

Comment: What is a `TaskList`? If you want to use Meteor reactive and as its intended, you should probably be using a `Meteor.Collection` and not a class of your own.

Comment: What is in your javascript console when this happens?

Comment: Do you use some meteorite model-package or something? Else you're doing the collection creation wrong as Andrew Mao points out.

Comment: It does not output any error in neither meteor console nor javascript browser console. I dont use any package, only backbone and jquey. When I was using autopublish and insecure packages, it behaved correctly.

Comment: The collection is already created. I'm not creating a new collection but a new document in the collection. The new object is not instanceof TaskList, as 'this' is not used in the contructor.

Comment: Finally, Subscribing again after inserting document worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a Collection.allow rule on the server, what happening is most probably you removed the insecure package, thus requiring explicit rules for each db action i.e. insert, update, delete.

```
oTaskList = new Meteor.Collection("tasklist");

oTaskList.allow({
insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return userId === doc.user_id;
 },
update: function (userId, doc) {
    console.log(EJSON.stringify(doc));
    return userId === doc.user_id;
 }
});
```

this code should run on the server only or either by putting it in the `/server` directory in your app or inside a `Meteor.isServer` conditional block

more about meteor allow http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

more about code running on server only http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_isserver